# Magento 2: Mailchimp or Sendgrid; pros and cons?

Tags: magento2.2, mailchimp

Based on your experiences with both extensions, which one would you recommend, and what would be the most important criteria for choosing?

Comment: please have look this link https://www.getapp.com/marketing-software/a/mailchimp/compare/sendgrid-cloud-based-email-infrastructure/ 

https://crozdesk.com/compare/sendgrid-vs-mailchimp-vs-dotmailer

and this one 

https://stackshare.io/stackups/mailgun-vs-mandrill-vs-sendgrid

Comment: Hi; thanks for sharing; have you also used one of these? what is your experience on it?

Comment: I have used MailChimp and sendgrid, depends on my experience MailChimp is best at all.